# If $G$ is a compact Lie group acting effectively on $X$ then it is a subspace of Homeo$(X)$?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group acting effectively on a simply connected space $X$. Let Homeo$(X)$ be the group of all homeomorphisms of $X$ with itself given the compact open topology.

**Is the topology on $G$ the same as the subspace topology it inherits from Homeo$(X)$?** If not then is one topology finer than the other?

I'm not quite sure where to begin here. If I can somehow show that $G$ is closed in Homeo$(X)$ then I will be done. But I am unsure how to proceed (or even if it is true).

My ultimate goal is to see if $G$ is compact as a subspace of Homeo$(X)$. So even if I can show that the subspace topology on $G$ is contained in the topology of $G$ then it is enough (I'm not sure how to prove this either). However I was wondering if the two topologies are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [answer by Eric Wofsey](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663871/what-is-the-relation-between-the-usual-topology-of-s1-and-its-subspace-topolo/1663881#1663881) to another similar question of mine, I figured out the answer to this question.

The two topologies agree if $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff.

If $X$ is locally compact then by the [proposition A.14 here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATapp.pdf) we have that $G\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ is continuous. Now since a continuous, injective map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism onto its image, we are done.